# Transliteration of Cyrillic

Tags: orthography, alphabets, transliteration, conlang

I have created a language that uses the Cyrillic alphabet, but I'm unsure as to how I can transliterate these letters for English-speaking readers:

Ii - this is pronounced as a hard letter 'i', as in 'ink'.

Ии - this is pronounced 'ee', as in 'feet'.

Йй - this is pronounced 'y', as in 'boy'.

I prefer the look of the words when I transliterate all three letters as 'i', but I fear this may be confusing for readers? Are there specific diacritical marks to show the different pronunciations?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Since you can pretty much transcribe any sound in Cyrillic (once you go beyond the subset used in Russian), I think it would be more sensible to start by specifying what the segments of this language are. Or at least list the Cyrillic letters you use: e.g. do you include any of ӝ, ӫ, ӻ, ҡ, ҥ, ҧ, ҩ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The English sound 'i' as in 'ink' is closer to `Ыы` [ɨ], which is usually transliterated into the Latin alphabet as `Yy`. And don't forget, there's also a letter `Її` that you can use as you like, in reality it's used in the [Ukrainian Cyrillic alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukrainian_alphabet) and is pronounced as [ji]. Also, the [Serbian Cyrillic alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serbian_Cyrillic_alphabet) uses the Latin `Jj` for [j], so if you use the three of them, `Їі`, `Іі`, and `Jj`, you'll have all of them with dots.